ShapeChange - cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ShapeChangeConfiguration'
I am doing a transformation from UML model to DDL SQL (databaseSystem is PostgreSQL). I configured the configuration xml file. I believe that it is not necessary to state what is in it, but I will attach the content of the xml file if anyone is interested. The problem is that when executing ShapeChange it tells me that the configuration of the xml file is not good because it does not have a root  element and can't read schemaLocation atribute spec. in ShapeChangeConfiguration root elem. I have it as you can see in the attached content.

What do you think is the problem?


<ShapeChangeConfiguration
    xmlns="http://www.interactive-instruments.de/ShapeChange/Configuration/1.1"
    xmlns:sc="http://www.interactive-instruments.de/ShapeChange/Configuration/1.1"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://shapechange.net/resources/schema/ShapeChangeConfiguration.xsd">
    <input>
        <parameter name="id" value="input" />
        <parameter name="inputFile" value="C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\LADAM.qea" />
        <parameter name="inputModelType" value="EA7" />
        <parameter name="publicOnly" value="true" />
        <xi:include href="https://shapechange.net/resources/config/StandardAliases.xml" /> <!--"Modularizacija modela tj modifikacija nazvia kekih svojstava (ne atributa)"-->
    </input>
    
    <transformers>
    
        <Transformer class="de.interactive_instruents.ShapeChange.Transformation.Flattening.Flattener" id="A" mode="enabled" input="input">
            <rules>
                <ProcessRuleSet name="flattener">
                
                    <rule name="rule-trf-all-flatten-name" />
                    <rule name="rule-trf-prop-flatten-multiplicity"/> <!-- stvara onoliko klonova nekog atributa, kome je maxOccurs u UML-u više od 1,koliko ije maxOccurs, treba zasititi asocijacije n:m sa sljedećim pravilom-->
                    <rule name="rule-trf-prop-flatten-multiplicity-keepBiDirectionalAssociation"/> <!--Ovo vredi za sve n:m, pogledaj prethodni kom-->
                    <!--ZBOG PRETHODNA DVA ELEMENTA ĆU DA ODEM NA FUNKC. ELEMENT TARGETS i da postavim pravilo koje sam upravo obezbedio <rule name="rule-sql-all-associativetables"> što kreira od sačuvanih m:n vezi asociativne tablice-->
                    <rule name="rule-trf-prop-flatten-type"/>   
                    <rule name="rule-trf-cls-flatten-inheritance"/>
                </ProcessRuleSet>
            </rules>
            <parameters>
                <ProcessParameter name="flattenObjectTypes" value="false" />
                <ProcessParameter name="maxOccurs" value="10"/> <!--Ovo govori da stranka ima max 10 uloga-->
                <ProcessParameter name="keepOriginalNameAsCode" value="true"/> <!-- ovo je jos upitno, ali predpostavka mi je da je bez mojih postavki podrazumjevano false tj. da pretvara imena u kodove i.e. alias-e-->
            </parameters>           
        </Transformer>
        
        <Transformer class="de.interactive-instruments.ShapeChange.Transformation.Profiling.Profiler" id="B" mode="enabled" input="A">
             <parameters>
                <ProcessParameter name="constraintHandling" value="remove"/>
             </parameters>
                <rules>
                    <ProcessRuleSet name="profiler">
                        <rule name="rule-trf-profiling-processing-keepAssociationAsIs"/>
                        <rule name="rule-trf-profiling-postprocessing-removeProfileInfos"/>
                    </ProcessRuleSet>
                </rules>
        </Transformer>

        <Transformer calss="de.interactive-instruments.Transformation.Adding.CodeListLoader" id="TRF-CL-LOADER" mode="enabled" input="B">
            <rules>
                <ProcessRuleSet name="cl_load_rules">
                    <rule name="rule-trf-cl-loadCodes"/>
                </ProcessRuleSet>
            </rules>
            <parameters>
                <ProcessParameter name="codeListSourceCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
            </parameters>
        </Transformer>
        
    </transformers>
    
    <targets>
        <Target class="de.interactive-instruments.ShapeChange.Target.SQL.SqlDdl" inputs="B,TRF-CL-LOADER" mode="enabled">

                   <!--Primeti da nema id, razlog je logica, i inputs a ne input -->
                
                <targetParameter name="srid" value="31467" />
                <targetParameter name="defaultEncodingRule" value="mojePraviloZaKreiranjeBaze"/>
                <targetParameter name="outputDirectrory" value="C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\GML_LADM\SQL"/>
                <targetParameter name="outputFilename" value="DDL_for_pgAdmin"/> <!--fali ekstenzija jer podrazumjeva da je to obicni .txt fajl -->
                <targetParameter name="databaseSystem" value="PostgreSQL"/> <!-- znam da je ovo i po default ali eto-->
                <targetParameter name="dbOwner" vlue="public"/>
                <targetParameter name="idColumnName" value="br."/>
                <targetParameter name="primaryKeySpecification" value="GENERATE ALWAYS AS IDENITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 ORDER NOCACHE) PRIMARY KEY"/><!--moja predpostavka je da je ovo isto sto create sequence naziv da bih imao nextvalue kao oid-->
                <targetParameter name="foreignKeyColumnSuffix" value="_FK"/>
                <targetParameter name="createReferences" value="true"/><!-- ogranicenja prenesenog kljuca-->
                <targetParameter name="foreignKeyOnDelete" value="Restrict"/>
                <targetParameter name="foreignKeyOnUpdate" value="no Action"/>
                <targetParameter name="deletePreExistingDataModelPackage" value="true"/><!-- delete if exists u sustini-->
                
                    <rules>
                        <EncodingRule name="mojePraviloZaKreiranjeBaze" extends="sql"> <!--extend su pravila kodiranja za sql(svi) a name je proizvoljan i definise moje modifikacije pravila sql--> 
                            <rule name="rule-sql-all-associativetables"/> <!-- Ovo proizilazi iz Flattenera multzplicity-->
                    
                        </EncodingRule>
                    </rules>
                    
                <mapEntries>
                    <!--  targetType: use 'cond:' to indicate that conditional type selection needs to be performed, with the following string identifying the nature of the type mapping (e.g. 'textOrCharacterVarying').  -->
                    <!--  param: used to indicate special nature of the type, for example 'geometry' to indicate that the map entry is for a geometry type.  -->
                    <!--  ISO/TS 19103  -->
                    <MapEntry type="CharacterString" rule="*" targetType="cond:textOrCharacterVarying{size=500}" param="defaultValue{quoted=true}"/>
                    <MapEntry type="URI" rule="*" targetType="cond:textOrCharacterVarying" param="defaultValue{quoted=true}"/>
                    <MapEntry type="Boolean" rule="*" targetType="boolean" param="defaultValue{true=TRUE;false=FALSE;quoted=false}"/>
                    <MapEntry type="Integer" rule="*" targetType="integer" param=""/>
                    <MapEntry type="Decimal" rule="*" targetType="numeric" param=""/>
                    <MapEntry type="Number" rule="*" targetType="numeric" param=""/>
                    <MapEntry type="Real" rule="*" targetType="numeric" param=""/>
                    <MapEntry type="Measure" rule="*" targetType="numeric" param=""/>
                    <MapEntry type="Date" rule="*" targetType="date" param="defaultValue{quoted=true}"/>
                    <MapEntry type="DateTime" rule="*" targetType="timestamp with time zone" param=""/>
                    <MapEntry type="character varying" rule="*" targetType="varchar" param=""/>
                    <MapEntry type="Short" rule="*" targetType="smallint" param=""/>
                    <MapEntry type="Long" rule="*" targetType="bigint" param=""/>
                    <MapEntry type="varchar" rule="*" targetType="cond:textOrCharacterVarying{size=500} param=defaultValue{quoted=true}"/>
                    <MapEntry type="char" rule="*" targetType="char(3)" param="length"/>
                    <!--  ISO/TS 19107  -->
                    <MapEntry type="GM_Point" rule="*" targetType="POINT" param="geometry"/>
                    <MapEntry type="GM_MultiPoint" rule="*" targetType="MULTIPOINT" param="geometry"/>
                    <MapEntry type="GM_Curve" rule="*" targetType="LINESTRING" param="geometry"/>
                    <MapEntry type="GM_MultiCurve" rule="*" targetType="MULTILINESTRING" param="geometry"/>
                    <MapEntry type="GM_Surface" rule="*" targetType="POLYGON" param="geometry"/>
                    <MapEntry type="GM_MultiSurface" rule="*" targetType="MULTIPOLYGON" param="geometry"/>
                    <MapEntry type="GM_Object" rule="*" targetType="GEOMETRY" param="geometry"/>
                
                
            
                    <!-- fk-->
                
                </mapEntries>
        </Target>
    </targets>
    
</ShapeChangeConfiguration>

I also get an error with the example recommended by the community for practice, the example is on github https://github.com/ShapeChange/ShapeChange/blob/master/src/test/resources/sql/basic/testEA_sql.xml, I just removed the elements that were not of interest to me for testing the example (removed all target-s except the one for SQL DDL and the log element)  I downloaded https://github.com/ShapeChange/ShapeChange/blob/master/src/test/resources/sql/basic/test_sql.qea. Modified xml conf file from https://github.com/ShapeChange/ShapeChange/blob/master/src/test/resources/sql/basic/testEA_sql.xml follows below
Error:


<ShapeChangeConfiguration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://shapechange.net/resources/schema/ShapeChangeConfiguration.xsd">
    <input id="INPUT">
        <parameter name="addTaggedValues" value="code" />
        <parameter name="inputModelType" value="EA7" />
        <parameter name="inputFile" value="C:\Users\Korisnik\Downloads\test_sql.qea" />
        <parameter name="appSchemaNameRegex" value="Test$" />
        <parameter name="sortedSchemaOutput" value="true" />
        <xi:include href="https://shapechange.net/resources/config/StandardAliases.xml" />
</input>
    
    <transformers>
        <Transformer
            class="de.interactive_instruments.ShapeChange.Transformation.Flattening.Flattener"
            input="INPUT" id="step1" mode="enabled">
            <parameters>
                <ProcessParameter name="targetNamespaceSuffix"
                    value="/flat" />
                <ProcessParameter name="maxOccurs" value="3" />
                <ProcessParameter name="flattenObjectTypes" value="false" />
                <ProcessParameter name="codeByTaggedValue" value="code" />
            </parameters>
            <rules>
                <ProcessRuleSet name="flattener">
                    <rule name="rule-trf-cls-flatten-inheritance" />
                    <rule name="rule-trf-prop-flatten-multiplicity" />
                    <rule name="rule-trf-prop-flatten-types" />
                    <rule name="rule-trf-all-flatten-name" />
                </ProcessRuleSet>
            </rules>
        </Transformer>
        <Transformer
            class="de.interactive_instruments.ShapeChange.Transformation.Naming.NamingModifier"
            input="step1" id="step2" mode="enabled">
            <parameters>
                <ProcessParameter name="suffix" value="_SUFFIX" />
                <ProcessParameter name="modelElementNamesToAddSuffixRegex"
                    value="Feature(2|3)|F(2|3)" />
            </parameters>
            <rules>
                <ProcessRuleSet name="rules">
                    <rule name="rule-trf-add-suffix" />
                </ProcessRuleSet>
            </rules>
        </Transformer>
    </transformers>
    <targets>
        
        <Target class="de.interactive_instruments.ShapeChange.Target.SQL.SqlDdl"
            inputs="step2" mode="enabled">
            <targetParameter name="defaultEncodingRule" value="sql" />
            <targetParameter name="outputDirectory" value="C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\GML_LADM\SQL" />
            <targetParameter name="size" value="-1" />
            <targetParameter name="srid" value="31467" />
            <targetParameter name="createReferences" value="true"/>
            <targetParameter name="createDocumentation" value="true"/>          
            <targetParameter name="documentationTemplate" value="[[definition]]" />
            <targetParameter name="documentationNoValue" value="" />
                                <mapEntries xmlns="http://www.interactive-instruments.de/ShapeChange/Configuration/1.1">
                        <!-- targetType: use 'cond:' to indicate that conditional type selection needs to be performed, with the following string identifying the nature of the type mapping (e.g. 'textOrCharacterVarying'). -->
                        <!-- param: used to indicate special nature of the type, for example 'geometry' to indicate that the map entry is for a geometry type. -->
                        
                        <!-- ISO/TS 19103 -->
                        <MapEntry type="Boolean" rule="*" targetType="bit" param="defaultValue{true=1;false=0;quoted=false}"/>
                        <MapEntry type="CharacterString" rule="*" targetType="cond:textOrCharacterVarying" param="defaultValue{quoted=true}"/>
                        <MapEntry type="DateTime" rule="*" targetType="datetime2" param=""/>
                        <MapEntry type="Date" rule="*" targetType="date" param="defaultValue{quoted=true}"/>
                        <MapEntry type="Integer" rule="*" targetType="int" param=""/>
                        <MapEntry type="Real" rule="*" targetType="numeric" param=""/>
                        <MapEntry type="Number" rule="*" targetType="numeric" param=""/>
                        
                        <!-- ISO/TS 19107 -->
                        <MapEntry type="GM_Curve" rule="*" targetType="geometry" param="geometry"/>
                        <MapEntry type="GM_MultiCurve" rule="*" targetType="geometry" param="geometry"/>
                        <MapEntry type="GM_MultiPoint" rule="*" targetType="geometry" param="geometry"/>
                        <MapEntry type="GM_MultiSurface" rule="*" targetType="geometry" param="geometry"/>
                        <MapEntry type="GM_Object" rule="*" targetType="geometry" param="geometry"/>
                        <MapEntry type="GM_Point" rule="*" targetType="geometry" param="geometry{USING=GEOMETRY_AUTO_GRID;BOUNDING_BOX=(-1000,-1000,1000,1000)}"/>
                        <MapEntry type="GM_Surface" rule="*" targetType="geometry" param="geometry"/>
                        
                        <!-- ISO/TS 19107 -->
                        <MapEntry type="CI_Citation" rule="*" targetType="nvarchar(max)" param=""/>
                        
                        <!-- ... more to be added as required -->
                        <MapEntry type="Short" rule="*" targetType="smallint" param=""/>
                        <MapEntry type="Long" rule="*" targetType="bigint" param=""/>
                        
                        <!-- other ISO -->
                        <MapEntry type="Date" rule="*" targetType="date" param=""/>
                    </mapEntries>
        </Target>
        

    </targets>
 </ShapeChangeConfiguration>



Basically, the problem is with the root element

Dear Sir/Madam user2856 , it is common knowledge that the declaration of an XML document is not mandatory, even sometimes as in parsers such as Java DOM or SAX is undesirable, and ShapeChange uses SAX. However, I set it up and it doesn't change anything. Also, even on the github link I wrote, you will not see in the examples that the root element appears, it is almost always omitted.

use https://   instead of http://

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The error message has changed. Now it just has a problem with the root element. Why does it happen that if I don't use the SSL protocol for the http connection, thanks again for helping.C:\Users\Korisnik>java -jar "`C:\Users\Korisnik\Downloads\ShapeChange-3.1.0\ShapeChange-3.1.0.jar" -c "C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\testEA_sql.xml" "C:\Users\Korisnik\Downloads\test_sql.qea" cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ShapeChangeConfiguration'. (line 3, column 93) ShapeChange has encountered a fatal error and is aborting. Message: Invalid configuration file.
